# Setting DB Browser (SQLite) application as a default app for opening .sqlite files for all users

Tags: windows-server-2019, db-browser-sqlite

I need to set DB Browser application as a default app for .sqlite files for all users.
I tried to set applicationn in windows settings for .sqlite files but it was set only for me.
Also I tried to search for some domain policy but also with no result. I was searching also in registry but with no result.

Does someone know where I can set it for all users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an issue of system administration and has little to do with programming.

Comment: And what is the point of your comment?

Comment: Just that it's off-topic here. It might be better placed elsewhere, maybe superuser.com, for example.